# How do I create a type alias for an array of char with a fixed size?

Tags: arrays, rust

I can't figure out how to create a type so that:

```
type CountryCode = &[char] // only 3 chars in it, no more
```

Is it possible to do that with `type`, or should I use `struct` instead?

Comment: Aren't you looking for `[char, ..3]` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Expanding [@Levans' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27552159/create-a-type-an-array-of-char-with-a-fixed-size#comment43531505_27552159) a bit with example code:

```
type CountryCode = [char; 3];

fn print_it(code: CountryCode) {
    println!("{:?}", code);
}

fn main() {
    let code: CountryCode = ['u', 's', 'a'];
    print_it(code);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Complementing [@Shepmaster answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27553332/2687651), for any beginner like me **wondering if the type can be inferred**, yes it can:

```
type CountryCode = [char; 3];

fn print_country_code(code: CountryCode) {
    println!("{:?}", code);
}

fn main() {
    let explicit_code: CountryCode = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
    let implicit_code = ['d', 'e', 'f'];
    print_country_code(explicit_code);
    print_country_code(implicit_code);
}
```

This code outputs (as expected):

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
['d', 'e', 'f']
```

I also asked myself **if `Rust` enforces the expected length**, and it does:

```
type CountryCode = [char; 3];

fn print_country_code(code: CountryCode) {
    println!("{:?}", code);
}

fn main() {
    let not_a_country_code = ['b', 'r'];
    print_country_code(not_a_country_code);

    let also_not_a_country_code = ['f', 'r', 'a', 'n'];
    print_country_code(also_not_a_country_code);
}
```

Compiling this code generate these errors:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> type_alias_for_array_fixed_size.rs:16:24
   |
16 |     print_country_code(not_a_country_code);
   |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected an array with a fixed size of
   |                                           3 elements, found one with 2 elements
   |
   = note: expected type `[char; 3]`
              found type `[char; 2]`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> type_alias_for_array_fixed_size.rs:19:24
   |
19 |     print_country_code(also_not_a_country_code);
   |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected an array with a fixed size of
   |                                                3 elements, found one with 4 elements
   |
   = note: expected type `[char; 3]`
              found type `[char; 4]`
```

Comment: Yes, each combination of inner type and length of array generates a completely new type, causing the type mismatch error you see.