# What is the type for an array (not Vec) of numbers?

Tags: rust

I'm having trouble figuring out the proper type for an array (not a `Vec`). The following code doesn't compile:

```
fn sum(a: [f32]) -> f32 {
    return 3.0;
}

fn main() {
    let x = [0.0, 1.0, 2.0];
    print!("{}\n", sum(x));
}
```

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `[f32]: std::marker::Sized` is not satisfied
 --> src/main.rs:1:8
  |
1 | fn sum(a: [f32]) -> f32 {
  |        ^ `[f32]` does not have a constant size known at compile-time
  |
  = help: the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `[f32]`
  = note: all local variables must have a statically known size

error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:7:24
  |
7 |     print!("{}\n", sum(x));
  |                        ^ expected slice, found array of 3 elements
  |
  = note: expected type `[f32]`
             found type `[{float}; 3]`
```

What's the appropriate type for `a` in `sum`?

Answer (score 2):

The type of an array is `[ElementType; Length]`

- `[i32; 10]`
- `[char; 16]`
- `[u8; 3]`
- `[String; 5]`

Surprisingly, this isn't directly called out in [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/), except in the [operators and symbols appendix](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/appendix-02-operators.html#square-brackets). For that to be useful, you'd have to already know the syntax you needed!

However, the compiler does guide you towards the correct solution. Take the time to *fully* read the Rust compiler's error messages. They are usually very good and most have had a lot of effort put into them. Check out the note from your error; it tells you what type you have:

```
  = note: expected type `[f32]`
             found type `[{float}; 3]`
```

> `` found type `[{float}; 3]` ``

You can also [print out the type of a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21747136/155423):

```
let x: () = [0.0, 1.0, 2.0];
```

The fix for your specific function:

```
fn sum(a: [f32; 3]) -> f32 {
    3.0
}
```

See also:

- [What is the {integer} or {float} in a compiler error message?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41996784/155423)
- [How do I create a type alias for an array of char with a fixed size?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27552159/155423)
- [Passing array to function: array must have 'Sized' type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44864442/155423)
- [How to define a function with a generic fixed-length array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38941025/155423)
- [How do I print the type of a variable in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21747136/155423)

Comment: Is it possible to define the function so it works for any length? (without going into Vec) Some kind of template or generic?

Answer (score 0):

I am adding to Shepmaster's answer.

What you did, `[f32]`, is actually valid syntax. It means a slice (a list of elements) where the size is unknown at compile time. The problem with it is that you cannot pass something into a function if its size is not known at compile time.
The syntax suggested by Shepmaster is for an array with fixed size, so it works.

If you cannot avoid passing a slice, you can use a reference. A reference always has a fixed size, but can be used to access unsized data (I advise reading about it in the Rust documentation):

```
// The ampersand means that the function takes a reference to a [f32]
fn sum(a: &[f32]) -> f32 {
    return 3.0;
}

fn main() {
    let x = [0.0, 1.0, 2.0];
    print!("{}\n", sum(&x)); // Here, the ampersand makes a reference out of x
}
```